Send Request data with Application Insights Exception Data
To ensure all exceptions are logged by my ASP.NET MVC application, I've excluded exception data from adaptive sampling as follows:
<ExcludedTypes>Event;Exception</ExcludedTypes>

The issue I'm seeing in Application Insights portal is that although the exception itself is logged as expected, the request data that it's associated with is still being adaptively sampled. So sometimes the request information, like URL, etc. cannot be queried in Log Analytics.
Is there any way to ensure that request information associated with exceptions is also not filtered as part of adaptive sampling. Obviously without turning off adaptive request filtering completely.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
      <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
        <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
        <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
        <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
      </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
      <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
      </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Handlers>
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
      </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetrySinks>
    <Add Name="default">
      <TelemetryProcessors>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <ExcludedTypes>Event;Exception</ExcludedTypes>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
        </Add>
      </TelemetryProcessors>
      <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
    </Add>
  </TelemetrySinks>
  <ApplicationIdProvider Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
</ApplicationInsights>




Can you please share your ApplicationInsights configuration?

Can you provide the code you have tried?

@RithwikBojja. I have not tried anything as yet as I'm trying to understand whether this is possible via configuration, or if it will require some kind of adjustment to a CustomTelemetry.

Use the below  Custom Telemetry Initializer to get Exception with request details and even when adaptive sampling is true.
I followed Microsoft-Document and below code works:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore;
using Rithweb;

var rith = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
rith.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = true;
    options.DeveloperMode = rith.Environment.IsDevelopment();
    options.InstrumentationKey = rith.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:RithCon"];
});
rith.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RithOptnTel>();
rith.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryProcessorFactory, RithCusTelIn>();
rith.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var ri_ap = rith.Build();
if (!ri_ap.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    ri_ap.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    ri_ap.UseHsts();
}
------
------
ri_ap.Run();

RithCusTelIn.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class RithCusTelIn : ITelemetryProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider ri_sp;

    public RithCusTelIn(IServiceProvider rsp)
    {
        ri_sp = rsp;
    }

    public ITelemetryProcessor Create(ITelemetryProcessor r_n)
    {
        return new CustomTelemetryProcessor(r_n);
    }
}
public class CustomTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public CustomTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor ri_n)
    {
        this.Next = ri_n;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry r_val)
    {
        this.Next.Process(r_val);
    }
}

RithOptnTel.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;


namespace Rithweb
{
    public class RithOptnTel : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry rith)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rith.Context.Operation.Id))
            {
                rith.Context.Operation.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

In HomeController.cs, I added Exception to test:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception("Hello Rithwik Bojja, This is an Test Exception");
}

Output:


